# How a local Machine can interact with server?

Tags: .net, web-services, server, client, tcp

I have few cashier machines in a departmental store. These machines are all connected to site server.How can these machines interact with site server.Should I use web services or is there any other process I can use? I have an application deployed at cashier machines and another application deployed at server.Now server application wants to interact with with application at cashier machine..I am using .Net

Comment: You may want to expand your question - what machines are they? Are you developing software for these machines, or are you working with the software provided by your vendor? What kind of services do you want these machines to connect to?

Comment: I have an application deployed at cashier machines and another application deployed at server.Now server application wants to interact with with application at cashier machine.